# List Most Read Posts from last 7 days (with custom post type and other meta queries)

Tags: functions, meta-query, count

I am using following code in my `functions.php` to count the views of the post.

```
// function to display number of posts.
function getPostViews($postID){
    $count_key = 'post_views_count';
    $count = get_post_meta($postID, $count_key, true);
    if($count==''){
        delete_post_meta($postID, $count_key);
        add_post_meta($postID, $count_key, '0');
        return '0 View';
    }
    return $count.' Views';
}

// function to count views.
function setPostViews($postID) {
    $count_key = 'post_views_count';
    $count = get_post_meta($postID, $count_key, true);
    if($count==''){
        $count = 0;
        delete_post_meta($postID, $count_key);
        add_post_meta($postID, $count_key, '0');
    }else{
        $count++;
        update_post_meta($postID, $count_key, $count);
    }
}
```

And putting this code in `single_post_type.php`.

Then I am using following code where I want the list to be shown.

```
        $custom_query = new WP_Query( array(
            'post_type'=>'POST_TYPE',
            'posts_per_page' => 5,
                    'orderby'      => 'meta_value', 
                    'meta_key'     => 'post_views_count',
                    'meta_query' => array(
                        array(
                            'key' => 'qualified',
                            'value' => '1'
                        ),

                    ),
                ) );
```

It is working fine.

Now the new requirement is that it should count the number of views only from last 7 days. `wp-most-popular plugin` allows me to list most read from last 7 days but then I could not use the **meta_query** which is a must.
What could be solution for this ?

Comment: I would strongly advise against using post meta to store viewcounts, updating post meta on every single page load involves a performance hit, and means caching is impossible. The system collapses completely once varnish or object caching gets used. Use an external service to track page impressions instead

Comment: External service as in plugins or like google analytics ?

Comment: Google Analytics would be one, or some other piece of software you install on your server, make requests to it and cache the values, but don't use post meta and roll your own. If you need to install something else on your server, the software recommendations stack would be best, 3rd party services and software are off topic here

Comment: Okay thanks for the suggestion :). Currently I would like to use post meta for a few days to solve this problem. Any suggestions on that ? Because I won't be using cache for now. Thanks